# Lie algebra homomorphism of product

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, adjoint-operators

Let $\varphi$ be a Lie algebra homomorphism. By definition
$$\varphi[X, Y] = [\varphi(X), \varphi(Y)].$$
You can then use induction to show
$$\varphi(\mathrm{ad}_Y^n (X)) = \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(Y)}^n (\varphi(X)).$$
Hence
$$\varphi(e^{t \mathrm{ad}_Y (X)}) = e^{t \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(Y)}}(\varphi(X))$$
What I don't understand is why
$$\varphi(e^{\mathrm{ad}_X} e^{t\mathrm{ad}_Y} (Y)) = e^{\mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(X)}} e^{t \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(Y)}} (\varphi(Y))?$$

Comment: Make that $\phi(Y)$ in the last equation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to expand both exponentials.
$$\varphi(\mathrm{ad}_X^n \mathrm{ad}_Y^m (Z)) = \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(X)}^n (\varphi(\mathrm{ad}_Y^m(Z))) = \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(X)}^n \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(Y)}^m (\varphi(Z)).$$
Thus
$$\varphi(e^{\mathrm{ad}_X} e^{t \mathrm{ad}_Y} Y) = \varphi \left( \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{k! m!} \mathrm{ad}_X^k \mathrm{ad}_Y^m Y \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^m}{k! m!} \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(X)}^k \mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(Y)}^m \varphi(Y).$$
Therefore $\varphi(e^{\mathrm{ad}_X} e^{t \mathrm{ad}_Y} Y) = e^{\mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(X)}} e^{t\mathrm{ad}_{\varphi(Y)}} \varphi(Y)$.